# What is the correct way to import/require "vscode" inside the developer tools inside VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to call the following two functions from inside the "Developer Tools" in VS Code.

- `vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.getText()`
- `vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.setText()`

In extensions, I usually use `vscode = require("vscode");`, but this does not work inside developer tools.

I get the following error in developer tools:

```
Uncaught Error: Check dependency list! Synchronous require cannot resolve module 'vscode'. This is the first mention of this module!
    at s.synchronousRequire (loader.js:1206)
    at o (loader.js:1606)
    at <anonymous>:1:10
s.synchronousRequire @ loader.js:1206
o @ loader.js:1606
(anonymous) @ VM239:1
```

---

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of error]

---

**How can I do this? (or alternatively, find a workaround...?)**

Comment: Thanks Matt. My google fu didn't find that duplicate question (tried though!).

Comment: PS: If anyone comes across an extension that allows you to *interactively* evaluate javascript in the context of the editor (such that something like `vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.getText()` would work), please let me know!